# Upgrade Kubernetes Cluster using Terraform's provisioner

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

**Scenario:**

I have a situation where I don't have the liberty to use any market available Kubernetes upgrade tool like KOps or KubeSpray. So, I'm compelled to use Terraform to provision the instances and kubernetes is installed as part of bootstrapping using provisioners. Now, the catchy part is, my K8s cluster is running on version 1.11.6 and I want to upgrade it to 1.12.3.

**What I did:**

In the terraform scripts, I doubled node count and updated the K8s version. Then did the Terraform deployment. I was successful in upgrading the new nodes (the nodes formed after doubling count). Post which I terminated the instances running old version on K8s. Now I only have the new nodes with new version of K8s running on them. Then ran `terraform refresh` so as to sync the statefile with real resources which exist remotely on AWS.

**Problem**

To verify the statefile and remote are in sync, I ran `terraform plan` which shows some resources to be created. Basically, the plan shows it's going to create the new nodes again. Unable to understand why so !!

Please can someone clarify what's going wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

My K8s version map

```
type = "map"
default = {
        kubernetes = "1.11.5"
        etcd = "3.3.1"
        dockerCE = "18.06.1.ce-3.el7"
        cfssl = "1.2"
        kube-dns = "1.14.10"
        core-dns = "1.2.0"
        helm = "2.9.1"
        calico-node = "3.0.6"
        calico-cni = "2.0.5"
        calico-kube-controller = "2.0.4"
        nginx-ingress-controller = "0.19.0"
}
```

My node count (for master below, but same for all nodes like etcd, ca, worker etc)

```
variable "MASTER_COUNT" {
        type = "map"
        default = {
                #bastion
                dev = "1"
                prod = "3"
        }
```

Terraform plan still shows below resources to be created. Basically it tries to recreate the nodes with older version of K8s, which shouldn't be as I have already ran `terraform refresh` which should sync my local and remote.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + module.master.aws_instance.ec2-master[0]
      id:                                                <computed>
      ami:                                               "ami-######"
      arn:                                               <computed>
      associate_public_ip_address:                       <computed>
      availability_zone:                                 <computed>
      cpu_core_count:                                    <computed>
      cpu_threads_per_core:                              <computed>
      ebs_block_device.#:                                "2"

  + module.master.aws_instance.ec2-master[1]
      id:                                                <computed>
      ami:                                               "ami-#######"
      arn:                                               <computed>
      associate_public_ip_address:                       <computed>
      availability_zone:                                 <computed>
      cpu_core_count:                                    <computed>
      cpu_threads_per_core:                              <computed>
      ebs_block_device.#:                                "2"

  + module.master.aws_instance.ec2-master[2]
      id:                                                <computed>
      ami:                                               "ami-######"
      arn:                                               <computed>
      associate_public_ip_address:                       <computed>
      availability_zone:                                 <computed>
      cpu_core_count:                                    <computed>
      cpu_threads_per_core:                              <computed>
      ebs_block_device.#:                                "2"

  - module.master.aws_instance.ec2-master[3]

  - module.master.aws_instance.ec2-master[4]

  - module.master.aws_instance.ec2-master[5]

# some other re-creations like Auto scaling group, Load balancer changes etc

Plan: 10 to add, 1 to change, 16 to destroy.
```

Comment: You should show your (minimal) Terraform code and the plan output for people to be able to follow what state you're in right now.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Terraform code added as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve this which means a K8s minor upgrade is successful. Below steps were followed during the course:

- Deploy a K8s cluster running version 1.11.2
- Double the node count, change version to 1.11.5 and re-deploy
- New nodes get created with updated version
- Remove nodes running old version i.e. 1.11.2
- Run `terraform refresh` so as to sync statefile with real world running Infrastructure
- Change the node count to 3 or half it.
- Run `terraform plan` and verify (multiple runs of refresh might be needed)
- Run `terraform apply` to apply changes.
- Statefile should be in sync with remote
- Run terraform plan which shouldn’t show any resources to be created

I will be trying a major version upgrade shortly and post the results here.

Comment: Major version upgrade also gets easily done with above approach. Only problem is we need to take care of what things have changed in newer version. Ex - I was getting some errors such as usage of command has changed, some options were deprecated.